# Unhandled CDBException while having an appropriate "catch"

Tags: c++, database, exception, mfc

I'm trying to handle DB connection error. If the `CDatabase::Open` (or the `CDatabase::OpenEx`) fails, the `CDBException` is normally thrown. But there's the thing. I can't handle it!

Here's my code:

```
try
{
    CDatabase db;
    db.OpenEx(L"DSN=INVALID_DSN;UID=noname", CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
    wprintf(L"Connection established.\n"
            L"DSN used: %s\n"
            L"DB name:  %s\n",
            db.GetConnect().GetBuffer(),
            db.GetDatabaseName().GetBuffer());
    db.Close();
    puts("Connection closed.");
}
catch (CDBException& e)
{
    e.GetErrorMessage(buf, BUF_SIZE);
    wprintf(L"CDBException: %s\n", buf);
}
catch (CException& e)
{
    e.GetErrorMessage(buf, BUF_SIZE);
    wprintf(L"CException: %s\n", buf);
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    printf("STD exception: %s\n", e.what());
}
// this section is the only way to handle exception thrown by the CDatabase::OpenEx
//catch (...)
//{
//    puts("Unknown exception");
//}
```

If the last `catch` is commented, I get error notification:

[image: **Unhandled exception at 0x76EAB727 in test-odbc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CDBException at memory location 0x004DF40C.**]

I use Visual Studio 2013 (Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use MFC specific exception handling macros: `TRY`, `CATCH`, and `END_CATCH`. MFC exceptions are pointer-only, and are deleted by special macros only.

See [example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e5twxsh.aspx)

EDIT: Inline example:

```
TRY
{
   // Do something to throw an exception.
   AfxThrowUserException();
}
CATCH(CException, e)
{
   if (m_bPassExceptionsUp)
      THROW_LAST();

   if (m_bReturnFromThisFunction)
      return;

   // Not necessary to delete the exception e.
}
END_CATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

MFC 1.0 was released in 1992, 6 years before the official ISO/IEC language specification for the C++ Programming Language was ratified. With exception handling being one of the features that solidified late in the process, MFC based its framework on the (then current) implementation for exceptions. [Exception Handling in MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t078xe4f.aspx) differs from today's exception handling in the following ways:

- MFC exceptions can only be caught by pointer. The paradigm *"throw by value, catch by (const) reference"* hadn't been established.
- The final exception handler must perform cleanup of MFC exceptions.

MFC provides macros to implement its exception handling (`TRY`, `CATCH`, `AND_CATCH`, `END_CATCH`, `THROW`, `THROW_LAST`) which you will find in existing code, but there is no requirement to use them in new code. The same functionality can be implemented using Standard C++ exception handling keywords (see [Exceptions: Converting from MFC Exception Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z28s5c.aspx) for instructions).

Applying this to your code:

```
try {
    CDatabase db;
    db.OpenEx(L"DSN=INVALID_DSN;UID=noname", CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
    wprintf(L"Connection established.\n"
            L"DSN used: %s\n"
            L"DB name:  %s\n",
            db.GetConnect().GetBuffer(),
            db.GetDatabaseName().GetBuffer());
    db.Close();
    puts("Connection closed.");
}
catch (CDBException* e) {  // Catch by pointer
    e->GetErrorMessage(buf, BUF_SIZE);
    wprintf(L"CDBException: %s\n", buf);
    // Dispose exception object; Do not use the delete keyword, because it can fail if
    // the exception is not on the heap.
    // Do not call Delete() in case you want to rethrow the exception.
    e->Delete();
}
catch (CException* e) {
    e->GetErrorMessage(buf, BUF_SIZE);
    wprintf(L"CException: %s\n", buf);
    e->Delete();
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {  // Catch by const reference
    printf("STD exception: %s\n", e.what());
}
catch (...) {
    // Only use after a 'catch(CException*)' clause to not leak MFC exception objects
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the MSDN docs, they (strangely) say to catch a pointer to the exception, not a reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19b8k939.aspx

```
try
{
}
catch(CDBException* e)
{
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes