# C26485 and pointer decay with TCHAR in exception handler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, array-pointer

I don't understand this [C26485](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26485?view=msvc-160) warning I receive.

My code is an exception handler:

```cpp
catch (CDBException* e)
{
    TCHAR szError[_MAX_PATH];
    e->GetErrorMessage(szError, _MAX_PATH);
    AfxMessageBox(szError);
}
```

It is saying:

> Expression `szError`: No array to pointer decay (bounds.3).

Both `GetErrorMessage` and `AfxMessageBox` are flagging this.

It doesn't make sense to me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That link seems to explain pretty well why this diagnostics exists and how to make it go away? Note that MFC is [very old](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253321/11683).

Comment: "*An explicit cast to the decayed pointer type prevents the warning*" - thus you can do: `e->GetErrorMessage(static_cast<TCHAR*>(szError), _MAX_PATH);
AfxMessageBox(static_cast<TCHAR*>(szError));` Alternatively: `TCHAR *pError = static_cast<TCHAR*>(szError); e->GetErrorMessage(pError, _MAX_PATH); AfxMessageBox(pError);`

Comment: Why not just replace TCHAR with CString? CString has the method PreAllocate(..).

Comment: @TomTom in 20+ years I have never used Preallocate! I would have to fully understand why to use it. But the function I am using will not accept a CString as a parameter. See Microsoft’s own example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfileexception-class?view=msvc-160#geterrormessage

Comment: I'm confused why the call to `GetErrorMessage` would issue this warning. The MFC source has appropriate SAL annotations (at least in VS 2019), communicating to the compiler that both arguments are related(`_Out_writes_z_(nMaxError)`). The array gets decomposed into a pointer/length pair, with the compiler able to see through everything. It **knows** that the pointer/length pair captures the full array information, and that it is correct, too. Maybe this is a bug in the static code analyzer.

Comment: @IInspectable Probably! I don't see why any core SDK code should flag errors! Particularly when the code is used as advertised.

Comment: `GetErrorMessage()` folllowed with `AfxMessageBox()` ? For this we have `ReportError()`. Also in this example you have forgotten to delete the MFC Exception. `e->Delete()`!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Again there is need to use TCHAR.  e->GetErrorMessage (err.GetBufferSetLength(_MAX_PATH)), _MAX_PATH));  This is what I mean with Preallocate() too.

Comment: So, well, this should be categorized as a bug in the static code analyzer, but [Microsoft decided not to](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C26485-false-positive/250721). *"It's by design, you suck, we rock!"* I get the message. And now I'm torn in between re-submitting an issue, or just letting go, because I'm not prepared for the level of frustration I would need to endure when dealing with a corporation that has quite obviously abandoned all interest in supporting platform-native developers. Maybe I can challenge myself by turning this into a psychological experiment...

Comment: @TomTom Why don't you offer a answer with working code? Just a suggestion.

Comment: @tom Using a `CString` silences the code analysis, but not because it is any safer. It just confuses the analysis enough to not see the array-to-pointer decay any more. And that's not even all: It does so by incurring a heap allocation, and the opportunity to throw another exception. The least thing you want in an exception handler is for it to fail, leaving you empty-handed. You can much more easily fool the code analysis by passing `&szError[0]` instead. No heap allocation required, and no exceptions either.

Comment: @IInspectable So `e->GetErrorMessage(static_cast<TCHAR*>(&szError[0]), _MAX_PATH);` ?

Comment: That's doing too much. Even if valid, you only need either one of these: `static_cast<TCHAR*>(szError)` or `&szError[0]`. Though, really, this is a spurious warning (on both function calls, actually), that you do not need to address. If you keep the code as-is, nothing bad will come of it. It's perfectly valid, and doesn't have the slightest chance of failing. If you can hold back, you may just want to temporarily disable the warning for this section of code (accompanied by a `// TODO:` comment), and see whether my issue re-report gains any traction. I'll link here when it's posted.

Comment: [There](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c26485-ignores-sal-annotations/1558068), that one took a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This diagnostic is an unfortunate result of the code analysis taking too narrow a view, ignoring hints that are readily available. [C26485](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26485) warns against array-to-pointer decay, one of C++' most dangerous features. When passing the name of an array to a function that expects a pointer, the compiler silently converts the array into a pointer to its first element, thereby dropping the size information that's part of the array type.

Clients that call into an interface that accepts individual arguments (pointer and size) to describe an array must make sure that the size actually matches that of the array. This has caused countless [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/)'s, and there's no reason to believe that the situation is getting any better. Array-to-pointer decay **is** dangerous and having tooling guard against it is great. In theory.

Here, however, things are different. The declaration (and definition) of `GetErrorMessage` have [SAL Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations) that allow the compiler to verify, that pointer and size do match, at compile time. The signature is as follows:

```cpp
virtual BOOL GetErrorMessage(_Out_writes_z_(nMaxError) LPTSTR lpszError,
                             _In_ UINT nMaxError,
                             _Out_opt_ PUINT pnHelpContext = NULL) const;
```

The [`_Out_writes_z_(s)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/annotating-function-parameters-and-return-values) annotation establishes a compile-time verifiable relationship between the pointer `lpszError` and its corresponding array's size `nMaxError`. This is helpful information that should be taken advantage of whenever possible.

First, though, let's try to address the immediate issue, following the recommendation from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26485):

> An explicit cast to the decayed pointer type prevents the warning, **but it doesn't prevent buggy code**.

The most compact way to turn an array into a pointer to its first element is to literally just do that:

```cpp
catch (CDBException* e)
{
    TCHAR szError[_MAX_PATH];
    e->GetErrorMessage(&szError[0], _MAX_PATH);
    AfxMessageBox(&szError[0]);
}
```

This fixes the immediate issue (on both function calls, incidentally, even if for different reasons). No more C26485's are issued, and—as an added bonus—passing an incorrect value as the second argument (e.g. `_MAX_PATH + 1`) does get the desired [C6386](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6386) diagnostic (*"buffer overrun"*).

This is crucially important, too, as a way of verifying correctness. If you were to use a more indirect way (say, by using a `CString`, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69634665/1889329)), you'd immediately give up on that compile-time verification. Using a `CString` is both computationally more expensive, and less secure.

As an alternative to the above, you could also temporarily suppress the C26485 diagnostic on both calls, e.g.

```cpp
catch (CDBException* e)
{
    TCHAR szError[_MAX_PATH];
    // Decay is safe due to the _Out_writes_z_ annotation
    #pragma warning(suppress : 26485)
    e->GetErrorMessage(szError, _MAX_PATH);
    // Decay is safe; the previous call guarantees zero-termination
    #pragma warning(suppress : 26485)
    AfxMessageBox(szError);
}
```

Which of those implementations you choose is ultimately a matter of personal preference. Either one addresses the issue, with the latter being maybe a bit more preserving as far as code analysis goes.

A word on why the final call to `AfxMessageBox` is safe: It expects a zero-terminated string, and thus doesn't need an explicit size argument. The `_Out_writes_z_(s)` annotation on the `GetErrorMessage` signature makes the promise to always zero-terminate the output string on return. This, too, is verified at compile time, on both sides of the contract: Callers can rely on receiving a zero-terminated string, and the compiler makes sure that the *implementation* has no return path that violates this post-condition.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Andrew, I should post working code here.

Solution without using TCHAR

```
catch (CDBException* e)
{
   e->ReportError();
   e->Delete();
}
```

.

```
catch (CException* e)
{
  CString strError;
  e->GetErrorMessage(strError.GetBufferSetLength(_MAX_PATH), _MAX_PATH);
  strError.ReleaseBuffer();
  AfxMessageBox(strError);
  e->Delete();
}
```

For the second example, selon IInsepctable this silences only the code analysis.

And to remember, usually you must delete the CException pointer, which you have forgotten here?

Comment: I thought that TRY / CATCH you delete but not try / catch.